# Java - Iterating over a Map which contains a List

Tags: java, list, dictionary, set

First time here so I hope this makes sense!

I have a Map which contains a String as it's Key, and a List of Strings as it's Value. I need to iterate over all vlaues contained within each List within the Map.

So, first I want to get the Keys, which works:

```
Set<String> keys = theMap.keySet();
```

This returns me a Set containing all my Keys. Great :)

This is where I've got stuck - most of the info on the web seems to assume that the values I'd want returned from the Key would be a simple String or Integer, not another Set, or in this case a List. I tried `theMap.values()` but that didn't work, and I tried a forloop / for:eachloop, and neither of those did the trick.

Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
for(List<String> valueList : map.values()) {
  for(String value : valueList) {
    ...
  }
}
```

That's really the "normal" way to do it.  Or, if you need the key as well...

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  String key = entry.getKey();
  for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

That said, if you have the option, you might be interested in [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [`ListMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), which is a lot like a `Map<K, List<V>>`, but has a lot more features -- including a `Collection<V> values()` that acts exactly like what you're asking for, "flattening" all the values in the multimap into one collection. (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: Spot on :) I'd gone over so many variations of this - turns out the thing I'd got wrong was how I was using the value returned by the second foreach loop. Many thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I recommend iterating over `Map.entrySet()` as it is faster (you have both, the key and the value, found in one step).

```
Map<String, List<String>> m = Collections.singletonMap(
    "list1", Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"));

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> me : m.entrySet()) {
  String key = me.getKey();
  List<String> valueList = me.getValue();
  System.out.println("Key: " + key);
  System.out.print("Values: ");
  for (String s : valueList) {
    System.out.print(s + " ");
  }
}
```

Or the same using the Java 8 API (Lambda functions):

```
m.entrySet().forEach(me -> {
    System.out.println("Key: " + me.getKey());
    System.out.print("Values: ");
    me.getValue().forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
});
```

Or with a little bit of Java Stream API mapping hardcore and method reference :-)

```
m.entrySet().stream().map(me -> {
    return "Key: " + me.getKey() + "\n"
        + "Values: " + me.getValue().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    })
    .forEach(System.out::print);
```

And the output is, as expected:

```
Key: list1
Values: s1 s2 s3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Map<String, List<String>>`

The left hand side `String` is the key, the right hand side `List<String>` is the value, which in this case is a `List` of `String`s

Answer (score 0):

Another example with the Java 8 API (lambda function).
When you want to iterate over:

```
Map<String, List<String>> theMap = new HashMap<>();

theMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
       System.out.println("KEY: " + key);
       System.out.print("VALUES: ");
       value.forEach(System.out::println);
});
```