# iterate over a map of collections eg : Map< Key, <List<Value>>

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary, set

I am looking for the best way to iterate over a map having collections as a value.

Let's consider the map to be like :

```
Map< Key, <List<Value>> map;
```

I want to extract the values in a list/ set. something like

```
List<Value>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Iterating over a Map which contains a List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075826/java-iterating-over-a-map-which-contains-a-list)

Comment: map.values() if you would have read the map javadoc !

Answer (score 0):

Look at the doc of [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()) method in Map interface.

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map

`map.values()` will give you a Collection of `List<Value>`